# How to show an element in front?

Tags: css

I was setting some section and I want to show a section in front but it's not working. 
I tried *z-index* but it's not working

I want that the listed product should come in front with their product content(Check link).
and one more thing it should not push the footer below
https://ibb.co/wKB0Zxj

My site is this
https://www.snatchu.com/product/toothpaste-squeezer-5-colors/

Comment: `z-index` works only in combination with `position`. Also, you shouldn't just post a link to your site; post a [mcve] instead.

Comment: Check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I go through your site there is a class `.slick-list` and it contains that card on which you are applying `z-index`. There may be many solutions and one of them is by adding `overflow-y:auto` in `.slick-list` and it will solve your problem.

```
.slick-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```